# Find Last Second Occurrence of word in a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I Have to find out second last occurrence of word in a string Using String Methods :

`String input = "Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi Afternoon";`

Output should be

```
Output = Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM GoodNight Hi Afternoon
```

Could you please help in below code Somehow it is replacing all the afternoon with GoodNight:

```
    System.out.println(input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"));
    String subString =input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon")-1);
    System.out.println(subString);
    System.out.println("substrint total length " + subString.length());
    System.out.println("Last index of "+subString.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"));
    String replaceString = subString.substring(subString.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"), 50);
    System.out.println(subString.replace(replaceString, "GoodNight"));
```

Comment: This kind of thing needs to be thought in a logic fashion. Further, to use Java for this purpose, at least for beginning steps, is out of sense. You need to start scanning of the word wanted from end of the text, find first occurrence of the word wanted, hold its index, then again start scanning from that index.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did like this

```
void replaceString3(String input) {
    int lastIndex = input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon");

    String tempString = input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"));
    
    //Storing last index 
    int secondLastIndex = tempString.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"); 
    
    String replaceString = tempString.substring(secondLastIndex); 
    
    // Replace String 
    String finalReplacedString = replaceString.replace("Afternoon", "GoodNight");
    
    System.out.println("\nOutput: "+tempString.substring(0,secondLastIndex)+ finalReplacedString + input.substring(lastIndex));
    }
```

Comment: Downvoted because your answer is *effectively* no different than what others have provided (mine included with `replace`, except yours will replace all occurrences not just the one you want), in addition to it will fail, as Andreas pointed out, when there are not 2 instances found in the string. It will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach is using substring as you displayed and other answers provide.

If you feel like living life on the edge you can use regex replace taking advantage of back references for a one-liner:

```java
input.replaceFirst("(.*)(Afternoon)(.*)(?=(\2))", "$1GoodNight$3");
```

This would satisify the following scenarios:

```
Input: Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi Afternoon
//Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM GoodNight Hi Afternoon

Input: Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi
//Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi GoodNight GM Afternoon Hi

Input: Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM
//Hi Afternoon Hello GoodNight Hi Afternoon GM

Input: Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon
//Hi GoodNight Hello Afternoon

Input: Hi Afternoon Hello
//Hi Afternoon Hello

Input: Hi Afternoon
//Hi Afternoon

Input: Hi Hello
//Hi Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find the last index of search string.Then get the substring without last search string.

Now find the last index in substring then it will be the second last search string starting index.

Then replace search string with new string using the substring method.

```
String input = "Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi Afternoon";

String searchString = "Afternoon";
Integer secondLastIndex =
    input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf(searchString)).lastIndexOf(searchString);
input = input.substring(0, secondLastIndex) + "GoodNight"
    + input.substring(secondLastIndex + searchString.length());
```

Output:

```
Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM GoodNight Hi Afternoon
```

Comment: Unnecessary autoboxing: Don't use `Integer` when `int` will do. --- What is purpose of `lastIndex` variable? It is never used. --- Using `substring()` to find second-last index is sub-optimal, when there is another `lastIndexOf()` method that works faster. --- Code crashes if the search string cannot be found twice.

Comment: @Andreas Ok then I revert to my initial solution then, maybe I misinterpreted your comment  sorry.

Comment: No, you didn't. I just found it funny that your solution ended up being the exact same as mine. I had no problem with the change, which is why I added the wink emoji.

Answer (score 0):

## [`String#substring​(int beginIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi Afternoon";

        // Get the substring without the 'Afternoon'
        String substr1 = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"));

        // Get the substring without the second last 'Afternoon'
        String substr2 = substr1.substring(0, substr1.lastIndexOf("Afternoon"));

        // Create the final string by replacing the second last 'Afternoon' with
        // 'GoodNight' and reinstating the remaining substrings as they are
        String finalStr = substr2 + "GoodNight"
                + input.substring(substr1.lastIndexOf("Afternoon") + "Afternoon".length());

        System.out.println(finalStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM GoodNight Hi Afternoon
```

**[Update]** [Courtesy Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970115/find-last-second-occurrence-of-word-in-a-string-in-java/62970897#comment111356953_62970897)

You can do it also by using [`String#lastIndexOf​(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int)) as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi Afternoon";

        // Get the index of the last 'Afternoon'
        int index1 = input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon");

        // Get the index of the second last 'Afternoon'
        int index2 = input.lastIndexOf("Afternoon", index1 - 1);

        // Create the final string by replacing the second last 'Afternoon' with
        // 'GoodNight' and reinstating the remaining substrings as they are
        String finalStr = input.substring(0, index2) + "GoodNight" + input.substring(index2 + "Afternoon".length());

        System.out.println(finalStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM GoodNight Hi Afternoon
```

Comment: Using `substring()` to find second-last index is sub-optimal, when there is another `lastIndexOf()` method that works faster. --- Code crashes if the search string cannot be found twice.

Answer (score 0):

To find the second last index, first call [`input.lastIndexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-), then call [`input.lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-int-), passing in the value from the first call.

You can now build the result using [`input.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) and [`input.substring(int beginIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-).

```java
static String replaceSecondLast(String input, String search, String replacement) {
    int lastIdx = input.lastIndexOf(search);
    int secondLastIdx = (lastIdx <= 0 ? -1 : input.lastIndexOf(search, lastIdx - 1));
    if (secondLastIdx < 0)
        return input;
    return input.substring(0, secondLastIdx) + replacement +
           input.substring(secondLastIdx + search.length());
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(replaceSecondLast(
        "Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM Afternoon Hi Afternoon",
        "Afternoon", "GoodNight"));
```

*Output*

```
Hi Afternoon Hello Afternoon Hi Afternoon GM GoodNight Hi Afternoon
```